# Simple JS graphical editor to build JSON trees

Tags: javascript, json, angular, drawing

I need to display a series of questions on my web app. Those questions can follow a tree structure (i.e: if you answer yes to question 1, go to question 2, else go to question 3). Think "you are the hero books".

I went with a JSON tree model for my data, and so far, everything works perfectly.

However, the JSON input can grow very big and complex, and setting it up is not user friendly, and very error prone, so I was thinking of building an editor that would help generating the JSON that would then be used in my app.

Basically my question is: what is the best way to make an extremely simple graphical editor that spits out JSON?

I have looked at a few options: building it from scratch with canvas, using drawing libraries (p5, d3...) to do the heavy lifting, or using diagram building libraries (MxGraph, gojs ...). My guess would be that using those libraries is my best bet, but it feels like a big time investment to learn the libraries for such a simple use case.

As an example, here is a simple JSON I use to generate my questions:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "Question": "Question 1",
        "QuestionType": "Options",
        "Answers": [
            "yes",
            "no"
        ]
    },
    "Children": [
        {
            "Data": {
                "Question": "Question 2",
                "QuestionType": "Options",
                "Answers": [
                    "yes",
                    "no"
                ]
            },
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Data": {
                        "Question": "Question 3",
                        "QuestionType": "Options",
                        "Answers": [
                            "yes",
                            "no"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Children": [
                        {
                            "Data": {
                                "Question": "Question 3a",
                                "QuestionType": "Text",
                                "Answers": [
                                    "Type in your answer"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Data": {
                        "Question": "Question 3",
                        "QuestionType": "Options",
                        "Answers": [
                            "yes",
                            "no"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Children": [
                        {
                            "Data": {
                                "Question": "Question 3a",
                                "QuestionType": "Text",
                                "Answers": [
                                    "Type in your answer"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Data": {
                "Question": "Question 2",
                "QuestionType": "Options",
                "Answers": [
                    "yes",
                    "no"
                ]
            },
            "Children": [
                {
                    "Data": {
                        "Question": "Question 3",
                        "QuestionType": "Options",
                        "Answers": [
                            "yes",
                            "no"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Children": [
                        {
                            "Data": {
                                "Question": "Question 3a",
                                "QuestionType": "Text",
                                "Answers": [
                                    "Type in your answer"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Children": []
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "Data": {
                        "Question": "Question 3",
                        "QuestionType": "Options",
                        "Answers": [
                            "yes",
                            "no"
                        ]
                    },
                    "Children": [
                        {
                            "Data": {
                                "Question": "Question 3a",
                                "QuestionType": "Text",
                                "Answers": [
                                    "Type in your answer"
                                ]
                            },
                            "Children": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, its pretty big for a very straightforward poll.

I need to show a canvas where the user can place block with editable info (question, question type, answers), and link those blocks to show parent/child relationship. And then transform that graph into a JSON object as shown before (but that should be the easy part). Something like that: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOhBP.jpg

Im working with angular 6 for info.

I'm sure I might have overlooked some simpler options of doing what I want to do (maybe the model is overly complicated to begin with), so any insight or help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks a lot

Comment: From my experience, most questionnaires are generic DAGs rather than trees, so you can have a simpler model with a linear list of nodes (no `Children`) and labels (`if answer=yes goto questionX`). This is simpler to edit (just as text) or, if you want it look cool, pretty straightforward with d3.js (e.g.https://bl.ocks.org/nitaku/7512487)

Comment: Thanks. I went with a tree as I needed to be able to navigate back and forth and it seemed simpler at the time, but thats a good point. The d3 example looks great, if its as easy as they make it look that could very well be all I needed inded